# Join a view to another table

Tags: postgresql, view

Is it possible to join a view with another table in SQL? If so, how?

I have a query on Oracle db which has specific fields. I need to re create the same query on PostgreSQL but some of the data in the PostgreSQL query are coming from a view... And that view has missing information. It's a pretty complex view, so I don't want to NOT use it for now.

For example, in Oracle I do this:

```
SELECT
d.dos_id,
trunc(d.dos_creation, 'MM') as Cohorte,
sum(v.ver_etude + v.ver_direct) as encaissé
from t_dossier d
left outer join v_versement v
on v.dos_id = d.dos_id
```

In the Postgres one, I'm using a view. But the view does not return "dos_id" so I cannot explicitly join v_versement with the view.

Is there a way to force a view to return specific fields at runtime which weren't there when creating the view?

Comment: no - when you create a view you specify its definition. even if you select star, postgres translates it to exact list of columns. after view is created you cant change columns

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the table and view in question. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't force it

> to return specific fields at runtime which weren't there when creating
>   the view

You can create or replace it with limitation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name
>   already exists, it is replaced. The new query must generate the same
>   columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the
>   same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but
>   it may add additional columns to the end of the list. The calculations
>   giving rise to the output columns may be completely different.

example:

```
t=# create view v2 as select now();
CREATE VIEW
Time: 36.488 ms
t=# create or replace view v2 as select now(),current_user;
CREATE VIEW
Time: 8.551 ms
t=# create or replace view v2 as select now()::text,current_user;
ERROR:  cannot change data type of view column "now" from timestamp with time zone to text
Time: 0.430 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had not realised that I can actually use the view without creating it...

So I edited the SQL statement that makes up the view, added the fields that I needed and used the code of the view without having to create a new view (creating a new view would mean outsourcing it to another company, which would cost us money..)

Thanks :)